# Aggregation on 'one to many' for matrix view in Django

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I have two tables like below.

These are in 'one(History.testinfoid) to many(Result.testinfoid)' relationship.
(Result table is external database)

```
class History(models.Model): # default database
    idx = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    scenario_id = models.ForeignKey(Scenario)
    executor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    createdate = models.DateTimeField() 
    testinfoid = models.IntegerField(unique=True) 

class Result(models.Model):  # external (Result.objects.using('external'))
    idx = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    testinfoid = models.ForeignKey(History, to_field='testinfoid', related_name='result')
    testresult = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('idx', 'testinfoid'),)
```

So, I want to express the Count by 'testresult' field in Result table.

It has some condition such as 'Pass' or 'Fail'.

I want to express a count query set for each condition. like this.

> [{'idx': 1, 'pass_count': 10, 'fail_count': 5, 'executor': 'someone', ...} ...
>   ...
>    {'idx': 10, 'pass_count': 1, 'fail_count': 10, 'executor': 'someone', ...}]

Is it possible?

Comment: Have a look at the aggregation docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: @KarimNGorjux I added a more specific title, because it is a much more interesting question than to say "Read the docs."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a **two level aggregation** where the second level should be displayed as table columns - "**matrix view**".

**A)** Solution with **Python loop** to create columns with annotations by the second level ("testresult").

```
from django.db.models import Count
from collections import OrderedDict


qs = (History.objects
      .values('pk', 'executor', 'testinfoid',... 'result__testresult')
      .annotate(result_count=Count('pk'))
      )
qs = qs.filter(...).order_by(...)

data = OrderedDict()
count_columns = ('pass_count', 'fail_count', 'error_count',
                 'expected_failure_count', 'unexpected_success_count')
for row in qs:
    data.setdefault(row.pk, dict.fromkeys(count_columns, 0)).update(
        {(k if k != result_count else row['result__testresult'] + '_count'): v
         for k, v in row_items()
         if k != 'result__testresult'
         }
    )
out = list(data.values())
```

The class `OrderedDict` is used to preserve `order_by()`.

**B)** Solution with **Subquery in Django 1.11+** (if the result should be a queryset. e.g. to be sorted or filtered finally in an Admin view by clicking, and if a more complicated query is acceptable and number of columns `*_count` is very low.). I can write a solution with subquery, but I'm not sure if the query will be fast enough with different database backends. Maybe someone other answers.